# How to prevent shortcut virus from affecting my pendrive and external disk?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, virus

I want to prevent the virus from execute or change things on my devices (flash drives and usb hard disks), not "cleaning" all the PCs of the virus, I already know how to do that, but that's not my job and my own PC is not infected.

Thing is that I have to plug my devices into some infected PCs from time to time, and I think the virus trying to move some big folders/files have corrupted some of them. Seems possible to me because the devices don't stop working when connected and Windows is likely to not allow you to safely remove them. So you have to unplug them anyway.

I cannot confirm the corruption was because of this, but I want to know if there is a way of preventing the virus to affect my pendrive and usb hard disk.

Trying to accomplish this I have put the attribute read-only to all my files but the virus moved them anyway and also tried the Panda USB Vaccine but it blocks virus from running through autorun.inf and that it seems it is not the way this virus runs.

This, I think, is a well known Windows's virus but here is the description: it hides and moves all the files of the flash drive to a ".trashes" folder, adds shortcuts to them in the root of the drive, and puts a ".bat" file on the root of the flash drive with a number for name, like "2.bat". This batch file just changes directory and executes a vbs file with a weird name, that is inside a number-named folder, that seems random. When you double-click the shortcuts, I think they execute the .bat file, never checked. I think this virus affects in some way to GNU/Linux also but I cannot confirm. I hope some of you already use some trick to avoid it!

Comment: There is no full proof way to prevent a virus from affecting your external devices. A virus can always be written to "undo" whatever changes you are talking about. It could change a file to be written to even if read only. The best virus protection us to unplug your external devices.

Comment: Yeah, well, the trick is not to use infected systems.

Comment: Making a flash drive read-only would have been the answer, but it seems not possible / expensive according to what I am reading here on superuser. I'll look on tricks or some like that for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never trust any machine you're plugging a drive into, and always scan it (and/or reformat it) on trusted computer after use in an untrusted one.

Having said that, perhaps just [buy a flash drive](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=usb+flash+drive+write+protection&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Ausb+flash+drive+write+protection) that has a physical write-protect switch.

E.g.:

[image]